# Как заставить браузер без задержки отображать элементы добавленные в цикле javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Есть задача, по клику на кнопке начать в цикле выполнение тяжелых вычислений (скажем поиск простых чисел) с постепенным выводом результата в блок div. Попытался сделать это в лоб в цикле:

```
function onClick() {  
  var div = document.getElementById("container");
  for (let i = 0; i <= 1000; i++) {
       /*
       тут какие нибудь тяжелые вычисления
       */
       var new_element = document.createElement("div");
       new_element.className = "element";
       new_element.innerHTML = `${i}`;
       div.appendChild(new_element);
  } 
}
```

Но, при такой реализации, результаты выводятся на экран пачкой, только после окончания цикла, а до этого момента страница подвисает.

Подскажите, как правильно организовать подобную задачу силами js?

Comment: используйте `setTimeout`, рекурсивно добавляя новые таймауты

Comment: Используйте web-worker, для тяжелых вычислений самое оно. Плюс, там используются асинхронные события, так что ваша проблема с выводом исчезнет.